# Find specific value in HttpContext.Current.Cache

Tags: .net, httpcontext

I am having some trouble with this and can't quite understand why I can't get a specific value from my collection stored in the code below...

```
public Dog Get(string name)
    {
        Dog dog = null;

        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context.Cache[CacheKey] != null)
        {
            System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator en = context.Cache.GetEnumerator();

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                if (en.Key.ToString() == "AnimalStore")
                {
                    // I would like to use a foreach loop to look for a specific dog here but I get an error!
                    // foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
                    foreach (var item in en.Value)
                    {
                       // en.Value contains two Dog objects with data but I can't get at them or their properties....
                    }
                }

            }

            //dog = (Dog)context.Cache[CacheKey];
        }

        return dog;
    }
```

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator' because 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Could someone else explain why I can't just loop through my array to get Dog.name and do something like this: //return dogs.Find(p => p.name == name);  This is quite a confusing concept to me so I appreciate the help in understanding....

Comment: Why have all the enumeration stuff instead of `Cache["AnimalStore"]`?  Why are you checking for the presence of `Cache[CacheKey]` if you don't use it? Your error is different in your code and in your question, which one are you actually getting? Can you show the code where you put in the value into `Cache["AnimalStore"]'?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the object which you are trying to iterate does not implement `IEnumerable` interface.

It seems like `en.Value` is an object here (I don't have VS with me to test it right now). If it is then, you need to cast it into the appropriate type and if your cast type is a collection and does not implement `IEnumerable` interface, you need to call `AsEnumerable()` extension method by `System.Linq` in place. Otherwise, as I said casting it into appropriate type should work.